# use titanium appcelerator user as oauth for third party applications

Tags: oauth, appcelerator

I have a appcelerator titanium app, and I would like to use the same users and password for other apps, not related to appcelerator ACS or titanium, the question is: can I use appcelerator ACS as oauth for other applications?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with ACS to much but from documentation I can find below:

it is not proffered as the ACS mention in its documentation

> Your app must prove that it is allowed to talk to ACS. This keeps your
>   data secure by preventing anyone from making requests to ACS that
>   **impersonate** your app.

but you can create new app with new client-id as in ACS mention that:

> You can integrate ACS into your application using the REST API, the
>   Titanium SDK, or the ACS native iOS and Android SDKs.

http://docs.appcelerator.com/cloud/latest/#!/guide/acs_quickstart
http://docs.appcelerator.com/cloud/latest/#!/guide/acs_authentication